# Batch file reading a text file and trying to stop the process based on the reading value

Tags: batch-file, text, text-files

I've got a batch file that has to read a value from a text file. The text file contains only one word, "canceled" or "accepted".
I've tried a lot of things from internet and even from stackoverflow questions, but nothing works.

`for %%i in (./OSS_License/tmp_license_file.txt) DO if %%i EQ "Canceled" goto END`

This is my code. I tried with a single "%", I tried with double "%", I tried puting "i" between two "%" (%i%), but every time I get
`i was unexpected at this time`.

Any ideas?

Update: I tried this way and the same error comes out:
`for %i% in (./OSS_License/tmp_license_file.txt) goto CheckLicenseCompilanceResult`
`:CheckLicenseCompilanceResult`
`if %i EQ "Canceled" goto END`

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information, paying particular attention to the `For /F` syntax.

Comment: Another issue with your code is the `IF` comparison.  It is a literal comparison. If quotes are on one side of the comparison, they must be on the other side for the comparison to be true.

Comment: @Compo The problem was on what's after the FOR instruction, solved it, I'll post the solution. Thanks

Comment: @Squashman yes, I've just learnt this, the problem was the way I tried to call that IF statment. Thanks

Comment: No, the problem was that your `for` loop was reading a filename, not its content, the `/F` I specifically mentioned was required to read its content.

Comment: @Compo Oh, I forgot to mention that I tried using that /F and all the combinations of % with i, nothing worked

Comment: Well we can only comment on what you told us in your question, _and subsequent comments_, and you didn't tell us that, did you?

Comment: @Compo all subsquences contain only pause and exit. that's the only part that failed, something was wrong in the syntax, using this syntax works just fine

Comment: Your posted code, `for %%i in (./OSS_License/tmp_license_file.txt) DO …` was wrong, it doesn't matter what happened in the `DO` portion because the result, `%%i` would never have been `canceled` or `accepted`. It doesn't matter what you try to do to persuade us to the contrary, that was your predominant issue.

Comment: Use the Windows path separator`\ `rather than `/`! And where do you have the comparison operator `eq` from? You have not read the output of `if /?`, have you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, the problem was what's after that FOR instruction. This solved it:
`FOR /F %%i in (tmp_license_file.txt) do ( if %%i==closed goto RefusedLicense )`
I've added "()" for the DO command. It appears to work just fine now

Comment: The parentheses for the `DO` block are not needed for executing one line of code.

Comment: @Squashman I don't know, I don't usually work with these, it's just the way it works for me. If you could bring some explanations why this works and the one from the question doesn't it would be great. I'd like to update the response with some explanations. I mean, i returned an error, maybe using "==" instead of "EQ", I don't know and I'd appreciate some explanations